# FullCalendar, can the timeline/resource view be squeezed into the viewable frame rather than scroll left to right?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The "week" view, resource setup in its default form shows one day at a time, using the back/forward buttons to move the canvas left and right.  Although the events would be small if fixed to the view area, this is intentional to see all the resources compared for the week. So, can the calendar area be fixed to the viewing area, no horizontal scroll?

Im not quite sure if this would a FullCal attribute, an outside function or simply css.

Something similar to this:
[image]